# Criando link de um site para outro no cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Estou com um problema, estou criando um botão, que está em um site X, mas a controller a action do do link está no site Y. O meu problema é que quando clico no botão, ele referencia o controller a action direito, mas a base do site continua do Site X e não do Y.

```
<td> <?= (!empty($cnId)) ? $this->Html->link('Galeria', array('plugin'=>'Galeria','controller'=> 'Fotos','action' => 'index',$cnId),array('class'=>'btn btn-default')) : ''; ?> </td>
```

Ele está me linkando `http: X/galeria/fotos/index/$id`, mas eu queria que ele me linkasse para `Y/galeria/fotos/index/$id`. Como faço isso?

Comment: Segundo a documentação: http://api.cakephp.org/2.1/class-HtmlHelper.html#_link  `If $url starts with "http://" this is treated as an external link. Else, it is treated as a path to controller/action and parsed with the HtmlHelper::url() method.`. Você tem que fornecer alguma localização com http:// antes, caso contrário vai apontar sempre "internamente".

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível utilizar a estrutura *[routing array](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/glossary.html#term-routing-array)* para referenciar links externos. Para isso, você deve informar toda a *URL* no segundo parâmetro, sendo este uma *string*:

```
echo $this->Html->link('Galeria', 'http://...', array('class'=>'btn btn-default'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, tente isto:

```
<td> <?= (!empty($cnId)) ? $this->Html->url('Galeria', array('plugin'=>'Galeria','controller'=> 'Fotos','action' => 'index',$cnId),array('class'=>'btn btn-default')) : '';?> </td>
```

**OU**

```
<td> <?= (!empty($cnId)) ? $this->Html-link('http://', 'Galeria', array('plugin'=>'Galeria','controller'=> 'Fotos','action' => 'index',$cnId),array('class'=>'btn btn-default')) : '';?> </td>
```

Comment: Dessa maneira funcionou, muito obrigado á todos.
Pergunta editada com a resposta certa.

Comment: A sintaxe aqui dos dois métodos estão incorretas, segundo o [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html). De qualquer forma @MichelHenriq, não tem necessidade de editar sua pergunta. Basta deixar o seu problema original e marcar a resposta correta como aceita, assim poderá ajudar outros com a mesma dúvida.